# mysql access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. How to drop password for MySQL? Windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

First of all, need to say - all solutions that I faced on the StackOverflow is solutions for Ubuntu, so please be careful with question closing.

So, I installed MySQL server on windows 10 but can't use him.

Actually, I installed MySQL some time ago, and possibly I forgot the password (although I try all possible passwords).

So, I try to connect to the server from the workbench:

[image]

And get the error:

[image]

In which way I can restore or drop the password?

Comment: And the [official manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) recommended way?

Comment: Please enable skip-grant-tables in your C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server *\my.ini  config file and restart mysql service and that would bring mysql on with no authentication then you can alter the root user with a new password

Answer (score 1):

Please enable skip-grant-tables in your C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server *\my.ini config file and restart mysql service and that would bring mysql on with no authentication then you can alter the root user with a new password

> enable skip-grant-tables in your C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server *\my.ini config file